# Toyota 2.0 D4-D (1CD-FTV) engine versions

Tags: toyota, diesel, turbocharger, replacements

After having some issues with my Toyota after some work being done on the engine I'm now facing an issue I can't find explanation to. Full story here:

[Toyota Avensis Verso D4-D 2002 after turbo & timing belt replacement drives differently](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/40730/toyota-avensis-verso-d4-d-2002-after-turbo-timing-belt-replacement-drives-diff)

Specifically, I own Toyota Avensis Verso with the engine as in topic. I know that same engine was fitted in several different models (Corolla, Avensis, Avensis Verso and RAV4, maybe something else too), but now, after stumbling on this:

http://www.toyotaownersclub.com/forums/topic/164217-1cd-ftv-d4d-engine-replacement/

where it says:

> Turns out the turbo and in fact nearly all ancillary bits are
>   different on the Corolla to the RAV4 but of course it's the block that
>   matters and all parts are being swapped over. Engine is out of the Rav
>   from underneath and was not too difficult to do on the ground with an
>   engine hoist

it looks like it's just a engine block designation, not the full, actual unit. Which means that I'm in a pickle.

So the question is: Is it possible I was fitted with turbo from different model and that's why my Toyota drives differently than before replacement? Can anyone confirm this? And if this is the case what are the reliability and durability of the unit I have fitted now?

Comment: The Toyota experts are on the toyota forum you've linked to. Maybe you should post your questions there.

Comment: @cory - Please don't drive people away from the site. How do you know we don't have Toyota experts who frequent this site? And if we don't, wouldn't it seem better to bring the experts *here*?

Comment: I'm wondering if you've been having issues all along with your previous turbo with the new turbo acting as it should have in the first place. Also, have you done a reset on your ECU? You may need to bring the fuel mapping back to stock settings then let the ECU relearn what it's supposed to be doing now that it doesn't have to deal with a depreciated turbo. Just a thought.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Does 48 hrs with disconnected battery count as a reset? If yes, then it has been reset. The previous turbo - as I probably learned with the failure - was possibly not right for quite a while (let's call it 6 months). So I'm not discounting that option, too. Thanks for pointers.

Comment: It's just a hunch... as nobody answered his other question with anything but generic car knowledge. He needs Toyota people, and it's clear he's not getting what he needs here. I want him to get the help he needs, even if that means going somewhere else. I'm sorry if that makes me a bad guy...

Comment: @AcePL - Yes, 48 hours would have more than enough to reset it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - but just now it got me thinking. I'm reading on the ECU reset on Toyotas and it also mentions - I think it was your comment on another question on this forum - on relearning the idle. When mechanic put back everything together he basically jammed throttle in place so for about half an hour the car was burning the engine oil sucked in by turbo at a bit over 1500 RPM. Not exactly the "lots of start/stop cycles for few miles"? And by that we mean just start moving/stop moving or switch ignition on/off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after reading until my eyes bleed I stumbled onto this website:

https://garrett.honeywell.com/products/service-replacement/

Which explains very little and yet quite a lot.

It seems that there is just one version of this engine after all, and it was fitted in a very wide range of Toyota models.

**HOWEVER.**

There are differences between models in details like turbo. But not in a way I was afraid of and what's suggested by my question.

The Garret Turbocharger model GTA1749V is indeed the same for a lot of Toyotas, but versions can - and do - differ. Look at this model:
[image: This is the Turbo compatible with my Toyota CLM20 (Avensis Verso)]

And then compare it with:
[image: This is RAV4 turbo]

SO you can see that while they look essentially the same, some angles are different. And, obviously, they can be either adjusted or the engine compartment (and hoses) can take a different versions. Or it's just an aftermarket seller's spiel.

**HOWEVER.**

When clicking through the links for previous versions (Garret provides them for all retired parts the current one replaces), sometimes specific turbo fitted in CLM20 (Avensis Verso) links to newer version, but fitted in RAV4... Interesting and Confusing.

What's more, in some versions of Corolla and Avensis D4-D (both 66kW and 86kW, for years 2001-2003) the turbo fitted was yet another one - GTA1749LV... And some sellers say they can be swapped for GTA1749V one. Which is weird, because they are quite dissimilar.

I hope this will help another poor soul in similar situation to one I've found myself in.

Comment: Just to clarify: the engine (1CD-FTV) is essentially the same, thats right. But, as You suggested, there are differences in parts as intake- and exhaustmanifolds, turbos etc. My 2003 Corolla (88BHP/90HP, UK build) is NOT fitted with a Garret turbo, but with an IHI unit. It has part no. 17201-27050, and is named RHF4H/VB10/VB420052. The turbos in the two pictures match exactly, by the way. The reason they look different, is the angle at whitch the intake part is mounted. That is the Alu part of the assembly, and it can be rotated freely by loosening the four screws that holds it to the CHRA.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had 53 reg avensis and still have 05 plate rav4... Same 1cd-ftv engine... Avensis much smoother and quieter. Rav more agricultural noisier even at idle is a big difference. I reckoned there was a cam timing difference at least for more torque from the rav to pull the 4wd system.... A shame i do not have the avensis anymore to compare turbo , injectors and cam timing to see differences.